# How to create a none checkbox that unchecked other checkboxes if it's selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

How do I create a check box that's *none of the above* so when I check that option the remaining checkboxes should get unchecked and if I try to check the other options the *none* checkbox should be unchecked automatically.

It should also be that if the *none* checkbox is unchecked it should force the user to check atleast 1 of the remaining boxes.

```html
<label for="box1">
<input id="box1" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="1" >
item 1</label>
<label for="box2">
<input id="box2" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="2" class="check">
item2</label>
<label for="box3">
<input id="box3" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="3" class="check">
item3</label>
<label for="box4">
<input id="box4" type="checkbox" name="nums" checked="checked" value="none">
none of the above</label>
```

> It's not like a Master checkbox

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67618283/15979312

Comment: I just wrote a complete plain JavaScript example that works perfectly. After reviewing your question I realized that it lacks any jQuery or JavaScript. Do you have any jQ/JS code to post as a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#checkbox input').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'box4') {
            if ($('input#box4:checked').length) {
                $("input#box1").prop("checked", false);
                $("input#box2").prop("checked", false);
                $("input#box3").prop("checked", false);
            } else {
                $("input#box1").prop("checked", true);
            }
        } else {
            if ($('input#box1:checked').length || $('input#box2:checked').length || $('input#box3:checked').length) {
                $("input#box4").prop("checked", false);
            } else {
                $("input#box4").prop("checked", true);
            }
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox">

    <label for="box1">
        <input id="box1" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="1" >
        item 1</label>
        <label for="box2">
        <input id="box2" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="2" class="check">
        item2</label>
        <label for="box3">
        <input id="box3" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="3" class="check">
        item3</label>
        <label for="box4">
        <input id="box4" type="checkbox" name="nums" checked="" value="none">
        none of the above</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you made 2 answers?

Comment: @EnterNam try select item2 and then deselect it again, then nothing is selected.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I don't understand you. Can you tell me in detail?

Comment: how about chatting via skype? my skype id : live:.cid.1a3f7a80fa264ca1

Comment: @Nikita I don't understand why you ask for upvote? does rep means this much to you? You get up or downvoted depending on the quality of your answer.

Comment: @Nikita Please learn how this site works, If you should talk about a problem related to question/answer you should keep it on Stack Overflow, else it can be hard for others to see what thoughts is behind the question/answer. Also saying that you need upvote before updating answer is just bad. If you answer is good, it will normally get upvoted, so you should not ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$("[id^=box]").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is("#box4")){
      $("[id^=box]").not($("#box4")).first().prop("checked",!$(this).is(":checked"))
  } else {
      $("#box4").prop("checked", !$("[id^=box]").not($("#box4")).is(":checked"));
  }
});
```

This will do so if none of the 3 first checkbox is checked, checkbox 4 will be checked, and unchecked if 1 of the first 3 is checked.

**Demo**

```js
$("[id^=box]").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is("#box4")){
  $("[id^=box]").not($("#box4")).first().prop("checked",!$(this).is(":checked"))
  } else {
  $("#box4").prop("checked", !$("[id^=box]").not($("#box4")).is(":checked"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="box1">
<input id="box1" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="1" >
item 1</label>
<label for="box2">
<input id="box2" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="2" class="check">
item2</label>
<label for="box3">
<input id="box3" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="3" class="check">
item3</label>
<label for="box4">
<input id="box4" type="checkbox" name="nums" checked="checked" value="none">
none of the above</label>
```

Comment: Looks nice.  One issue: OP asked for *create a check box that's none of the above so when I check that option* - can't seem to tick "none of the above".  It nicely auto-ticks, but can't manually-tick.

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry I've missed that part, was a bit confused about the "Create a check box". since it was already created so misunderstood the last requirement

Comment: Works well without the `.first()` `$("[id^=box]").not($("#box4")).prop("checked",!$(this).is(":checked"))`

Comment: @freedomn-m reason why i used `.first()` it because op's requirement said that atleast 1 checkbox should be checked. so that is why

Answer (score 1):

I have combined the 2 answers on top and that works.

```js
$('#checkbox input').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'box4') {
        if ($('input#box4:checked').length) {
            $("input#box1").prop("checked", false);
            $("input#box2").prop("checked", false);
            $("input#box3").prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            $("input#box1").prop("checked", true);
        }
    } else if ($('input#box1:checked').length || $('input#box2:checked').length || $('input#box3:checked').length) {
            $("input#box4").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
$("[id^=box]").change(function() {
if ($(this).is("#box4")){
$("[id^=box]").not($("#box4")).first().prop("checked",!$(this).is(":checked"))
 } else {
 $("#box4").prop("checked", !$("[id^=box]").not($("#box4")).is(":checked"));
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox">

<label for="box1">
    <input id="box1" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="1" >
    item 1</label>
    <label for="box2">
    <input id="box2" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="2" class="check">
    item2</label>
    <label for="box3">
    <input id="box3" type="checkbox" name="nums" value="3" class="check">
    item3</label>
    <label for="box4">
    <input id="box4" type="checkbox" name="nums" checked="" value="none">
    none of the above</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you combine them?

Comment: Either of them should work on their own, the different between answers is that Nikitas and mine is that mine will work dynamic. So if you add more checkbox you don't have to change the js code.

Comment: If my answer did not work as you wanted it, then why did you not reply on my answer so I could improve it so it works as you want? When you combine these 2 answers your get code that runs multiple time for the same purpose and that is in general a bad idea.

Comment: It's okay, I'm only trying to teach you how this site works :)